# how to capture error on function "include" PHP?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

i need capture the last error on function "include" PHP.

I test with the functions "Exceptions", but unfortunately i have written above the function "include".

If I write after the function "include" does not show the exception.

**Example 1:**

```
try{
        throw new exception();
        require_once( $this->controller['path'] );
    }
    catch( exception $e )
    {
        print_r( error_get_last() );
    }
```

**This Return:** ...(Void)...

**Example 2:**

```
try{

        require_once( $this->controller['path'] ) OR throw new exception();;
    }
    catch( exception $e )
    {
        print_r( error_get_last() );
    }
```

**This return:** Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW in...

I purposely created a syntax error in the file to include. The idea is to trap the error so that you can debug them.

Anyone have any idea how to get this?

Guys! I need to catch syntax errors. Greetings!

Comment: Guys! I need to catch syntax errors.
Greetings!

Comment: @OlaErlandsenTriskel: You can't. Syntax errors fail at the tokenising level. Your code hasn't started to execute by then. You could include the file and run `token_get_all()` on the individual files. Not sure what happens if there was a parse error though (maybe an empty array)?

Comment: why do you want to test for the syntax errors? you have to do it at development time, not at run time

Comment: The issue still isn't clear. Are you trying to handle syntax errors in the included file, or are you referring to the syntax error in the second code sample?

Comment: I'm trying to handle all errors in the project.
for that also implement "set_error_handler" and "Exceptions" ... nothing works well, now I'm doing tests with your idea.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother with catching any and all errors like file inclusion errors. Including other required files is such a basic thing that something is fundamentally broken in your app layout if that doesn't work. The app should just die as quickly as possible with an error message if it doesn't even work at that level, which is exactly what `require` does. You just have to bootstrap the app at some point, including all needed dependencies is IMO part of that step. It does not fall into the "needs to be handled gracefully" category yet.

Comment: Note that `token_get_all` only gives you access to the PHP lexer and won't catch any errors generated by the parser proper.

Comment: @deceze what about a poor user? What he's supposed to see? an error message? a blank screen?

Comment: Not work, try in various ways, but does not work as I need...

Comment: @Col If the app can't even find all its include files, it has obviously never been run. Code in that condition should never be seen by a user anyway. Usually this will cause the web server to throw up its Error 500 page, which you can customize. If you *really* want to handle this in PHP, see my answer.

Comment: @deceze I purposely created a syntax error in the file to include. The idea is to trap the error so that you can debug them.

Comment: you have always an error message from PHP and you can use it to debug. it seems you are trying to use PHP wrong way. it is better to follow common patterns rather than trying to reinvent the wheel. a square one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, if you use `require`, it's always going to kill your app if the file cannot be included. There's no control over the outcome, you cannot do anything afterwards. If you want to have control over the success of file inclusions, use `include` and test its return value.

```
$success = include "foo.php";
if (!$success) {
    // the file could not be included, oh noes!
}
```

You can have syntactical differences on that like:

```
if (!(include "foo.php")) ...
```

This *will* trigger an `E_NOTICE` if the file cannot be included, which you cannot catch. But that's OK, since it'll help you debug the issue and the display of errors will be turned off in production anyway (right, *right*?).

`or throw new Exception` doesn't work because `throw` is a statement and cannot be used where an expression is expected.

---

If you want to catch syntax errors in the *included* file, use [`php_check_syntax`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php)/it's successor `php -l <file>`.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax error is not in the included file?! Is this perhaps your question?

Comment: I purposely created a syntax error in the file to include. The idea is to trap the error so that you can debug them.

Comment: @Olaf Then please clearly state that the syntax error is in the included file! See updated answer.

Comment: Would this fail if the body of `foo.php` is `return FALSE;`?

Comment: If you want to find out if the include succeeded or not, you probably want to suppress the usual PHP error message if the include file is not found. Do that like this: '$success = @include "foo.php";'

Comment: Tested in PHP 5.6.40, 7.x, 8.x: `include "NoExistsFile.php";` will trigger 2 warnings

Comment: As of PHP 8.x: `require "NoExistsFile.php";` will trigger 1 warning and throw an `Error exception`... previous versión (PHP 7.x) will trigger 1 warning and 1 fatal error (aborting script).

Answer (score 5):

`require_once` is a language construct and not a function and you can't do short circuit with it.

To test if the file exists before you include it, you can use `is_file()`. If you want to test if the file is readable, you can use `is_readable()`.

You may also want to use `include` which issues a `E_WARNING` if the file could not be found, not a `E_COMPILE_ERROR`.

Comment: he don't want to test if file exists, I believe, but rather if the file is *readable...*

Comment: lol, it turned to be somewhat funny one. including *implies* reading, so, it turned to be "To test if the file is readable, you can use is_file(). If you want to test if the file is readable, you can use is_readable()." :)

Answer (score 2):

i agree with alex, try to cath error with check the `file_exists()` then use an Exception

```
if(file_exists($this->controller['path'])){
    try{
       require_once( $this->controller['path'] );
    }catch(Exception $e){
          // throw error
    }
}
```

or use is_readable()

```
if(is_readable($this->controller['path'])){
    try{
       require_once( $this->controller['path'] );
    }catch(Exception $e){
          // throw error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most native PHP functions trigger errors rather than throwing exceptions. To convert PHP errors into exceptions you can set up a custom error handler:

```
function exceptions_error_handler($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) { 
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno); 
}
set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');
```

With this code you'll be able to catch all non-fatal errors as exceptions. Note that `require_*` functions throws fatal error, thus you'd have to use `include` instead.

As for handling syntax errors within the code itself, it is quite impossible, if you think about it a bit.